# PHP/MYSQL string clarification

Tags: php

Night, I would like a clarification please. Can I use in select query with php variables to specify the names of the fields? For Example:

```
<?php
$fields= "firstname, lastname, address";
$query = "SELECT $fields FROM friends 
WHERE firstname='test'";
...
?>
```

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes..........................................